# PersistenceException with Umlaut in path

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, javadb, toplink-essentials

I experienced an odd behavior with a **java desktop application that uses Toplink essentials** as persistence provider.

I have a single directory containing all I need for my application: a jar, a lib folder and a JavaDB database. The whole **directory is self-contained** (I copied it several times without problems, even between different computers).

Today I wanted to copy once more, **but my target folder contained a german Umlaut ü** (html: `&uuml;`).

**Starting my application failed, with an exception** that made it hard to find the reason why (see below).

Of course I know the old naming conventions, but I thought we already left that behind. So my question is, if there is **a way to make it run independent of directory naming**. It's important since I want to give the application to clients and have only little influence on install dirs.

System: Windows 7, JavaDB 10.5.3

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Application class jlabps.JLabPSApp failed to launch
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManage
r named JLAPS_EMB:  The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.
java:154)
        at jlabps.JLabPSView.initComponents(JLabPSView.java:401)
        at jlabps.JLabPSView.<init>(JLabPSView.java:47)
        at jlabps.JLabPSApp.startup(JLabPSApp.java:71)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class jlabps
.JLabPSApp failed to launch
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for E
ntityManager named JLAPS_EMB:  The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.
java:154)
        at jlabps.JLabPSView.initComponents(JLabPSView.java:401)
        at jlabps.JLabPSView.<init>(JLabPSView.java:47)
        at jlabps.JLabPSApp.startup(JLabPSApp.java:71)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Odd.  What JVM are you using?

Ensure you have the latest TopLink Essentials patch, I remember an issue with spaces, but not Umlats.

You could also try upgrading to EclipseLink and see if the same issue occurs, if it does please log a bug.

Comment: Thanks James. Will try to get the latest patches. My JVM: "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I think I have the latest toplink version. Don't know how tricky it is to upgrade to EclipseLink or is it just a thing of replacing some jars?